# swiftc: Possible values for "-target" command line option

Tags: swift

There is Swift compiler option **-target**:

```
$ swiftc -h
...

 -target <value>         Generate code for the given target
...
```

Where from can I get all possible values for compiler option **-target** (i.e: `x86_64-apple-ios11.0`, `x86_64-apple-macosx10.12`, ...) ?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you already know the format of the target triple, but there's an infinite number of possible values since the OS version is part of this. But knowing the format allows you to construct any triple you desire, e..g `x86_64-apple-macosx10.14` is going to be the triple for next year's OS.

Comment: Seems like **-target** consisted from these parts: `[ARCHITECTURE]-apple-[PLATFORM][DEPLOYMENT_TARGET]`. But I need precise control.) Something like we can get with `xcodebuild -showsdks`.

Comment: Seems command line option `-target` of `swiftc` compiler is similar to one for `clang` compiler. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html#target-triple

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/utils/build-script-impl

Search the build script for terms like `SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT`, `SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_SDK`, `SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_ARCH` and `SWIFT_HOST_TRIPLE`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#===--- build-script-impl - Implementation details of build-script ---------===#
#
## This source file is part of the Swift.org open source project
# Each variable name is re-exported into this script in uppercase, where dashes
# are substituted by underscores. For example, `swift-install-components` is
# referred to as `SWIFT_INSTALL_COMPONENTS` in the remainder of this script.

KNOWN_SETTINGS=(
  # name            default      description
  # ... snip ...
  darwin-deployment-version-osx   "10.9"   "minimum deployment target version for OS X"
  darwin-deployment-version-ios   "7.0"    "minimum deployment target version for iOS"
  # ... snip ...
function set_build_options_for_host() {
  llvm_cmake_options=()
  swift_cmake_options=()
  cmark_cmake_options=()
  lldb_cmake_options=()
  swiftpm_bootstrap_options=()
  SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT=
  SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_SDK=
  SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_ARCH=
  SWIFT_HOST_TRIPLE=
  local host="$1"

  # Hosts which can be cross-compiled must specify:
  # SWIFT_HOST_TRIPLE and llvm_target_arch (as well as usual HOST_VARIANT flags)
  case ${host} in
    freebsd-x86_64)
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT="freebsd"
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_SDK="FREEBSD"
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_ARCH="x86_64"
      ;;
    cygwin-x86_64)
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT="cygwin"
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_SDK="CYGWIN"
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_ARCH="x86_64"
      ;;
# ... snip ...
    linux-*)
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT="linux"
      SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_SDK="LINUX"
      case ${host} in
        linux-x86_64)
          SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_ARCH="x86_64"
          ;;
# ... snip ...
        linux-aarch64)
          SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_ARCH="aarch64"
          ;;
# ... snip ...
    ;;
    macosx-* | iphoneos-* | iphonesimulator-* | \
      appletvos-* | appletvsimulator-* | \
      watchos-* | watchsimulator-*)
      case ${host} in
        macosx-x86_64)
          xcrun_sdk_name="macosx"
          llvm_target_arch=""
          SWIFT_HOST_TRIPLE="x86_64-apple-macosx${DARWIN_DEPLOYMENT_VERSION_OSX}"
          SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT="macosx"
          SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_SDK="OSX"
          SWIFT_HOST_VARIANT_ARCH="x86_64"
```