# `@available` attribute incorrectly constrained on macOS version

Tags: swift, macos

I've an issue with using [`FileHandle.read(upToCount:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/3516317-read) on macOS 10.15.7; whenever I attempt to do so, I get the following error:

```
error: 'read(upToCount:)' is only available in macOS 10.15.4 or newer
```

This constraint matches with what I can see at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Foundation.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftinterface
```

```
extension FileHandle {
  ...
  @available(OSX 10.15.4, iOS 13.4, watchOS 6.2, tvOS 13.4, *)
  public func read(upToCount count: Swift.Int) throws -> Foundation.Data?
  ...
}
```

I'm able to replicate this availability issue with a small test; with a `main.swift` like so:

```
@available(OSX 10.15.4, *)
func test() {}

test()
```

which gives me the same general error:

```
error: 'test()' is only available in macOS 10.15.4 or newer
```

If I change the `@available` constraint to either `OSX 10.15` or `OSX 10.15.0` this compiles fine, but `OSX 10.15.1` or higher will report the same error, which seems to indicate that the toolchain thinks the build target is 10.15.0. Looking at what `swiftc` is doing under the hood, though, it appears to be using the correct SDK and triple:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift \
  -frontend \
  -c \
  -primary-file main.swift \
  -target x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0 \
  -enable-objc-interop \
  -stack-check \
  -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk \
  -color-diagnostics \
  -target-sdk-version 11.1 \
  -module-name main \
  -o /var/folders/ml/3hynjc6s5v96y4k_wfy3gt6r0000gn/T/main-9906ee.o
```

Can anyone shed some light on to what is happening, and what I can do to convince my toolchain that these functions are available for me to build against?

Comment: What is the oldest macOS version your app should run at? What is the Deployment Target in the Build Settings?

Comment: @Willeke unspecified, I'm running everything from the command line. How would I set that from `swiftc` itself (if not `-target x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0` and `-target-sdk-version 11.1` as above)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with command-line builds. My log says `-target x86_64-apple-macos10.15.4`. See also [swiftc: Possible values for "-target" command line option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46532610/swiftc-possible-values-for-target-command-line-option)

Comment: @Willeke yes I created a new project and saw that different target scheme, I'm writing up an answer now. Thanks for mentioning this and looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

Use:

```
-target x86_64-apple-macos10.15.7
```

#### Long answer

Looking at what Xcode does, as suggested by @Willeke has put me on the right path. A new command-line project in Xcode passes:

```
-target x86_64-apple-macos10.15
```

to the Swift backend at compilation, which still fails due to the `@available` constraint, but modifying this to:

```
-target x86_64-apple-macos10.15.7
```

works as expected.

It is annoying that the use of corresponding `darwin` versions in the triple doesn't cause the same behaviour as the use of `macos` versions, but I imagine that this is due to the legacy of a time when there was only one Darwin based operating system coming out of Apple. Now, a given Darwin version can mean different versions of macOS, iOS, tvOS etc., each with different available API sets. ✌️